# How to assign a value obtained from spreadsheet to the value attribute of <input>?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working with an HTML template by Google Apps Script in Google Sheets. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to set the value attribute of   with a variable assigned from a value taken in spreadsheet.

My goal is to create an HTML template, in which the inputs already appear with the defined values, but editable.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do it like this:

In the HTML template, I use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <Title> Test email </Title>   
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1>Sending emails with values in Sheet </h1>
   <p></p>
   <p>Hello <?= Client_name ?>!</p>
   <p>We are confirming the order: <?= Order_number ?></p>
   <p></p>
   <p>The items requested are: </p> 
   <p><?= Items ?></p>
   <p></p>
   <p> Please confirm the order soon as possible.  </p>
   <p></p>
   <p> Thanks!</p> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Inside the Apps script code, you need to add the variables

```
  var vClient_name = 0;
  var vOrder_number = 1;
  var vItems = 2;
```

In my case, since I was going to use those values to send an email, I link those variables with the brackets like this:

```
 Emailtemp.Client_name = row [vClient_name];
 Emailtemp.Order_number = row [vOrder_number];
 Emailtemp.Items = row [vItems]
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I just couldn't with the <select> tag. Do you know how to do?
I tried like this:

`<div class="block">  
<label for="operacao">Operação</label>  
<select id="operacao" name="operacao" required>  
<option value="<?= operacaoCad ?>"></option>  
<option id="op-br" value="BR">BR</option>  
<option id="op-us" value="US">US</option>  
</select>  
</div>`

Comment: And if you try it like this: `<select id="operacao" name="operacao" required>        <option value="operacaoCad"><?= operacaoCad ?></option>        <option id="op-br" value="BR">BR</option>        <option id="op-us" value="US">US</option>   </select>`